# Perverse incentive / asymmetry on closes versus migration

Tags: discussion, migration

Recent questions here about inappropriate migrations remind me of an interesting bit of perverse incentive.

If a question closes with migration, it's gone. It will never be seen again unless diamonds intervene.

If a question closes for some other reason, it can come back. Particularly if it's a bikeshed, it's prone to return courtesy of being voted to reopen.

Thus, there's an incentive to migrate bikesheds to p.se. Yes, I try to be a good citizen and not 'migrate crap.'

I don't have an entirely viable counter-proposal, but it seems like this might deserve consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an incentive to move bikesheds to p.se because it is more of a subjective, talking shop - some questions fit there.  But there are plenty of questions that don't quite fit anywhere and need to be closed.

Migrating crap is bad, allowing bikesheds (or something with eeeek in the title!) to be closed and re-opened is also crap.

My close suggestion would be to make it increasingly harder for closed questions to to re-open; say increasing by one the votes needed to re-open every 24 hours.  So a question that is closed for a week is almost certain never to return.

My migration suggestion would be to make migration easier, but also make it easier for the migration to be rejected.  If it is rejected by the site it is migrated to then hit the flag rating of the people who suggested it should be migrated.

There are plenty of SE sites that would appreciate more new questions being migrated to them (for example [Project Management](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10947/project-management) which may not otherwise survive public beta) - so bikesheds are not universally unwanted!

Comment: New Area51 proposal idea: BikeShed.StackExchange.Com, where flogging dead horses is ALL we do.

Comment: Re: increasing required reopen votes: I don't think we need to be *quite* that drastic considering that reopen votes already expire after 48 hours.